# Hard Inverse Matrix calculation

Tags: matrices, self-learning, inverse, matrix-decomposition

I tried so hard but I am unable to solve this problem.

Find the inverse of the matrix $I+ab^T$ .

**Hint**: Try the form $cI+dab^T$ and find
$c$ and $d$.   What happens if $a^T b = −1$?

This is an exercise from A Primer  on  Linear models by Monahan ( Appendix A.69)

Comment: What did you get when you multiplied the matrices together?

Comment: There is no formula for the inverse of $I+ab^T$ without any conditions. For example, for $1\times 1$ matrices, this would be just like asking "what is the inverse of $1+ab$"?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the hint and multiply the suggested form by your matrix and set it equal to the identity matrix.
$$
(cI+dab^T)(I+ab^T) = cI +(c+d)ab^T+da\overbrace{b^Ta}^{\text{scaler}}b^T=cI +(c+d+db^Ta)ab^T=I
$$
Since $ab^T$ has rank at most one and cannot be a (nonzero) multiple of identity, the only way this sum is equal to identity is that the coefficient $(c+d+db^Ta)$ in front of $ab^T$ should be zero, and therefore the coefficient $c$ infront of $I$ has to be $1$.

$$
\implies c=1 \implies 1+d(1+b^Ta)=0.
$$

If $b^Ta\neq -1$ then $d = -1/(1+b^Ta)$, and the inverse matrix is given by
$$
(I+ab^T)^{-1}=I-(1+b^Ta)^{-1}ab^T.
$$
If $a^Tb= b^Ta=-1$, the matrix $I+ab^T$ is not invertible. Here is why: Let's multiply $a$ by $I+ab^T$
$$
(I+ab^T)a = a+ab^Ta=a-a = 0.
$$
That is, $a$ is an eigenvector of $I+ab^T$ with eigenvalue $0$. If one of the eigenvalues is zero, the matrix is not invertible.

Comment: It isn't exactly true that $ab^T$ can't be a multiple of the identity. We could have $ab^T = 0I = 0$. Of course in this case the inverse is simply $I$. This is a great answer, though! I saw this question earlier and it seemed impossible to me at first glance. Apparently not!